# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre content_main xml y activity_main xml en android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Al realizar una nueva activity en Android Studio me aparecen ambas junto al .java el nuevo `main_activity.xml` y el `content_main.xml`. Esto es distinto frente al activity inicial (main activity) que no tiene un content.xml equivalente.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre éstos?

Answer (score 2):

Diferencia sería el nombre y su contenido, en realidad ambos son Layouts que contienen elementos a desplegar en una interfaz de usuario.

El layout `activity_maim.xml` es el creado por default para ser cargado en la Activity por medio del método `setContentView()`, pero en realidad tu puedes cambiar el nombre de este layout e incluso cargar otro diferente para tu `Activity`.

**En conclusion la diferencia entre un layout u otro es simplemente su contenido.**

Puedes leer este articulo de nuestros amigos de "hermosa programación":

**[Layouts En Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/08/tutorial-layouts-en-android/)**